# is it correct to say "they laid pipe in the floor" or "they laid pipe under the floor"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

We often say "**on the floor**".

We say "**they laid tiles/carpet on the floor**".
What about **pipe or cable**?

is it correct to say "**they laid pipe in the floor**" or "**they laid pipe under the floor**"?

Comment: There's no absolute right and wrong here. There's no doubt pipes are usually laid ***under*** a floor, but personally, I might well use ***in*** if the pipes were actually what we call "underfloor heating" (i.e. - pipes that are *supposed* to give up heat underneath the floor, as opposed to simply being used to carry the hot water to radiators). That's to say, if the pipes are considered to be "part of the [heated] floor", you'd probably lay them ***in*** the floor. Much may depend on exactly what the speaker considers to be "the floor" (maybe he thinks it's just "the carpet").

Comment: Generally, pipes are laid before floors are built. Just saying. And tiles are laid on a concrete or cement floor. And you **run pipes** under a floor.

Comment: The choice might even be affected by which floor and what processes are involved. If the work is happening in the space below wooden floorboards, then "under" could make sense. But sometimes on a ground floor, it means chiseling into a concrete slab; this seems more "in" than "under."

Comment: I would say it might even depend on when in the process you are talking about. As the pipes are actually being installed in a building under construction? The workers for that might well say "in", as the surface isn't even there yet to be "under". Later, when the building is complete, someone just talking about what was done might well use "under", as there is now a surface to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cast** is also commonly used for such work in the construction industry, my line for over 3 decades already.  The pipe is cast together with the concrete floor, forming part of the latter.

**In** is used in such descriptions:

> They laid (or cast) pipes **in** the floor (slab).

For cables, we say

> They laid (or ran) cables in conduit cast **in** the floor (slab).

**Under** is less common and is usually limited to cases with a raised floor or similar:

> They laid pipes (or air-conditioning duct) **under** the raised floor.

> They laid (or ran) cables in cable trunking
> **under** the raised floor.